# Where do the users use Ubuntu's Development code name? (For ex. Utopic Unicorn)

Tags: 14.04

I was quite quizzed about, why Ubuntu is having this Code name. This names for the format of "Adjective Animal" (for ex, Trusty Tahr, Utopic Unicorn etc), it follows a rule of Adjective and Animal should start with same char and that too in alphabetical Order.

I was just thinking, when this code names are really used, If I have a 14.04 version, I would say that I have a Ubuntu 14.04 rather than saying I have a Utopic Unicorn. But, I just like to know how peoples normally use this words.

Comment: Without these amazing codenames it would be too boring. IMHO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is referenced in 'public speak' (you'll see it on this site a bit too). Generally it gets shortened to just the Adjective though. Trusty, or Oneric etc. It is also used in things like the apt repo lists also, eg:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
```

My assumption is that it stems from Debian's use of codenames such as wheezy or sid or squeeze etc.

To me the version and codename are used interchangeably in the industry, though the codename is usually shortened to the adjective only.